# Send Long string to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using `fabric.js`.I want to send the `canvas dataurl() string` to `PHP` via `AJAX`. Since I want to scale the canvas size, I am using `multiplier` property provided by the `Fabric.js` library

When I use the below code

```
var imgData       = _canvasObject.toDataURL({format: 'png'});
```

The ajax request is fast

But when I sclae the canvas using the `multiplier` property it takes aroun 2 minutes for the `ajax` request to be sent.

```
var imgData = _canvasObject.toDataURL({format:'png',multiplier: 3});//Takes 2 mins for AJAX request to be sent
```

What can be done?

Comment: You could send the non multiplied version and do it server-side, a lot of options depending on what is at your backend. Alternatively, you could send a blob version, 30% lighter than the dataURI version. Fabricjs doesn't support (yet ?) a toBlob method, so you'll have to either convert your dataURI to blob (slower) or to implement the multiplier + export to blob yourself (a bit harder but still very feasible). Personally, I would go with the server side solution.

Comment: ... that sounds like a good "Answer" to me, Kaiido!  **:-)**